# Angular - Change origin center of parent div to left-bottom

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cdk

I have a problem with the positioning of `<div>`.
This is my scenario:

I have a `parent div` that contains two `child div`. I am using `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` for drag and drop the two child div inside the parent div:

component.html

```html
<div class="badge-container" id="badge">
  <div
    (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)"
    class="badge-text"
    id="nominative"
    cdkDragBoundary=".badge-container"
    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragNominativePosition"
    cdkDrag
  >
    My Test
  </div>
  <div
    (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)"
    class="badge-text"
    id="nominative"
    cdkDragBoundary=".badge-container"
    [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragCompanyPosition"
    cdkDrag
  >
    My TEST test TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropOverviewExample implements OnInit{
  dragNominativePosition = {x: 0, y: 50};
  dragCompanyPosition = {x:0, y: 0};

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
}
```

In "component.ts", I set the position of the children's div using for both, the coordinate `x:0`.

My problem is that the position of children div is not on the left margin of parent div but on the center of parent div.
So I realized that the coordinates x:0 and y:0 correspond at the center of parent div.

I would like to know if there is a way to move x:0 and y:0 of parent div on the left-bottom like the classic cartesian plane.

This is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmrhxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-overview-example.ts)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you then want them stacked? bottom to top rather than downwards as now?

Comment: I would like if x: 0 and y: 0 the div was on bottom-left

Comment: So in the case you show there would be two divs one overlaying the other? (At the moment they appear one below the other with the first one in the box being fully visible as it's placed below the second one) - in CSS top terms).

Comment: Yes, in that case the two divs would overlap, but it wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved by rimoved from css .badge-container, "justify-content: center;".